# ES6: this is undefined despite using bind()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, closures, ecmascript-6

**Note: I am using Babel for my transpiler**

I am trying to implement an ES6 class with some notion of private methods. To do this I have declared a function outside of the class declaration, and I am trying to also make use of closure for DRY practices.

However, when my class method invokes the "private" method the context of **this** becomes undefined. I thought that using bind() was supposed to explicitly set the context, but it doesn't appear to be working.

```
function _invokeHttpService(httpMethod) {
    return (url, config, retries, promise) => {
      var s = this;
      // Do some additional logic here...
      httpMethod(url, config)
        .then(
          response => {
            s._$log.info(`Successful response for URL: ${url}`);
            promise.resolve(response);
          },
          error => {
            s._$log.error(`Request for URL: ${url} failed.`);
            promise.reject(error)
          });
    }
  }

  function _get(url, config, retries, promise) {
    _invokeHttpService(this._$http.get);
  }

  class httpSessionService {
    /*@ngInject*/
    constructor($log, $http, $q, $timeout, CODE_CONSTANTS, $rootScope) {
      this._$log = $log;
      this._$http = $http;
      this._$q = $q;
      this._$timeout = $timeout;
      this._$rootScope = $rootScope;
      this._CODE_CONSTANTS = CODE_CONSTANTS;
    }

    get(url, config, retries = 5) {
      var s = this;
      var deferred = s._$q.defer();
      _get(url, config, retries, deferred).bind(this);
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) creates a copy of a function with `this` set to the first argument.

```
var f = _get.bind(this);
f(url, config, retries, deferred);
```

What you want to use is [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) which is basically `bind` but the function is invoked immediately. The first argument is the value of `this` while any following arguments are passing to the function you're calling.

```
_get.call(this, url, config, retries, deferred);
```

`call` has a sister function called [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) which does the same thing but takes the actual arguments in an array.

```
_get.apply(this, [url, config, retries, deferred]);
```

Useful for when you're not sure how many arguments you're passing to a function.